# MySQLi Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference

Tags: php, mysqli

Colegas.

Tenho o seguinte código abaixo:

```
$conexao = new mysqli('127.0.0.1','root','','teste');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) die(trigger_error(mysqli_connect_errno()));

$cadastrar  = $conexao->prepare("INSERT INTO cad_produtos VALUES(?,?,?,?)");     
        $cadastrar->bind_param('iiss',
                                null,
                                '111',
                                '11',
                                '2016-03-01');
$cadastrar->execute();
$idCod = $cadastrar->insert_id;
```

Sendo que o tipo de dados são (seguindo a ordem): Int, Int, Varchar,Date.

Porém não está cadastrando.

Comment: Não deu erro nenhum?

Comment: Desculpe Krismorte... pensamos que fosse erro nosso, mas não é... vimos que não trás nenhum erro...apenas não cadastra. Verificamos se a nomenclatura estava certo, quantidade de campos, mas nada...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bind_param()` não aceita valores como segundo argumento, somente referências ou seja variáveis, faça a atribuição dos valores nela e problema resolvido.

O erro gerado é:

> Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in

Mude:

```
$cadastrar->bind_param('iiss', null, '111', '11', '2016-03-01');
```

Para:

```
$id = null;
$var = 111;
var2= 11;
$data= '2016-03-01';
$cadastrar->bind_param('iiss', $id, $var, $va2, $data);
```

Comment: Bingo rray... era isso mesmo... muito obrigado pela ajuda...

Comment: @Jose.Marcos essa é uma das diferenças do MySQLi para o PDO, no segundo é possível passar valores direto.